# Facing issue SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, spree

Hello I have included given gem in my gemfile:

```
gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

and further done settings in spree-admin in configuration < Mail method Settings
[image]

When I place order it gives me error

> 2016-05-10T07:16:32.164733+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.164734+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob]
>   [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [9526835c-d5e7-4434-b716-a98b68b75da1]
>   Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) in 471.29ms
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.164735+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 1395ms (ActiveRecord: 179.9ms)
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168574+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168583+00:00 app[web.1]: SocketError (getaddrinfo:
>   Name or service not known): 2016-05-10T07:16:32.168583+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in
>   `initialize' 2016-05-10T07:16:32.168584+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in`open'
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168584+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168585+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in`block in
>   do_start' 2016-05-10T07:16:32.168585+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168586+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in`call'
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168586+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `timeout'
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168587+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in`do_start'
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168587+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
>   2016-05-10T07:16:32.168587+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:113:in`deliver!' 2016-05-10T07:16:32.168588+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/spree_mail_settings-d416a1e35589/lib/spree/core/mail_method.rb:8:in
>   `deliver!' 2016-05-10T07:16:32.168588+00:00 app[web.1]:

Please guide me why I am facing this issue and what settings are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do settings in the admin section like this;

[image]